# Table nested div's height percentage doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, height, overflow

Refer to: [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/y6ZwR/123/)

I want the `.bottom` div to fit the remaining space of the container, and it's overflow to be scrollable. This works in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, but not Firefox.

The `.bottom` div's overflow works if you give it a fixed height of 100px, but not `height:100%` which is supposed to make it fit the window responsively.

I can't find anything on this. Is this a known issue?

Comment: I usually use javascript to do such things, but it's crazy how does your code even work in chrome and those browsers :D

Comment: Well, the container is supposed to fit flush inside the viewport. Firefox seems to have a different idea of what 100% means though...

Comment: no problem with container 100% height, it's relative to the viewport as you said. but what about .bottom height? it's 100%, what is it relative to?

Comment: relative to the container, which takes on the size of the viewport. I think the problem is that firefox renders "100% of the space needed for my child content" rather than "100% of available space in my parent"

Comment: As I know Those percents are relative to their parents full width or full height, not to the left available space in them..

Comment: so then the question is, why is the container height going off the page in firefox but not chrome?

Comment: um yes for me that's the real question, maybe you hack it by using the table display, not sure..